# .NET ODBC Oracle Params getting param name returned by db provider- possible?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, odbc, data-access, rdo

I'm converting some RDO code to ODBC Provider code in .NET.

The problem is parameter names were not specified in the orignal code, but param values were retrieved by parameter name after the command was executed.

Is there anyway to have parameter names populated by the provider once the command is executed so calling code can access params by name.

Let me show you an example of the declaration of param and accessing of it.

```
    With rdqryClntBasic
        .Parameters.Add(.CreateParameter) : .Parameters(0).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        .Parameters(0).DbType = DbType.String
        .Parameters(0).Value = sClntProdCd
```

End With

.EffectiveDate = ToDate(rdqryClntBasic.Parameters("dtEffDt").Value)

You can now see how this "used to work in RDO/VB".  For some reason it would accept this and know what the param names were after execution.  I imagine it had to do another round trip to the db to get this info.

Is there anyway to mimic this behaviour in .NET for ODBC Provider (using Oracle)?  Or am I stuck manually specifying the param names in the code (I understand this is the better option, but wondering what the alternative is to match the original code as closely as possible).

Answer (score 0):

No, parameters in ODBC are positional not by name.